# Mono on OS-X: Filesystem Watcher Handle Leak?

Tags: c#, macos, mono

I'm not entirely sure what's happening here, but something feels wrong....

First, my code:

```
routeWatcher = new FileSystemWatcher();
routeWatcher.Path = Folder;
routeWatcher.NotifyFilter = NotifyFilters.LastWrite | NotifyFilters.FileName | NotifyFilters.DirectoryName;
routeWatcher.Filter = "*.*";
routeWatcher.Changed += onRouteFolderChanged;
routeWatcher.EnableRaisingEvents = true;
```

Nothing especially interesting here, I just subscribe to monitor the folder supplied via Folder (A bunch further up my code)

This works just fine on Windows & the Microsoft runtime, and as expected it displays a single open handle- That for the folder.

Under OS-X on the other hand, I'm seeing an open handle for each file within the folder when using lsof -p or Activity Monitor.

Something however is a little odd, as I'd expect ulimit to be unhappy in a folder with over 256 files:

```
core file size          (blocks, -c) 0
data seg size           (kbytes, -d) unlimited
file size               (blocks, -f) unlimited
max locked memory       (kbytes, -l) unlimited
max memory size         (kbytes, -m) unlimited
open files                      (-n) 256
pipe size            (512 bytes, -p) 1
stack size              (kbytes, -s) 8192
cpu time               (seconds, -t) unlimited
max user processes              (-u) 266
virtual memory          (kbytes, -v) unlimited
```

This doesn't happen in a folder with 631 files, and everything appears fine.

Am I misunderstanding something, or have I hit some sort of Mono bug?

Comment: what version of mono are you using?

Comment: Latest (4.8) straight from Mono. OS-X version is el-Capitan

Comment: We are often seeing file handle leaks in Xamarin Studio / Visual Studio itself, so thanks for raising the question. It could be related to the problem we see.

Comment: Is there an Xamarin bug filed at all? I've disabled my filesystem watcher on Mac for the minute, but am happy to try and get to the bottom of it...

Comment: https://github.com/mono/monodevelop/pull/1906 ... this may be of some interest.

Comment: Thanks- I'll do some playing with that, although I suspect that disabling the filesystem watcher will be the ultimate solution for me, simply as I'm not particularly happy playing with low-level FS code. Subscribing to something from Mono is one thing, maintaining it myself is quite another :)